# Add custom tags to xml file in RobotFramework

Tags: xml, tags, robotframework, logfile

As of now I use the builtin function Log to store the desired information. Such as serial numbers and measured voltages and currents. This is fine for the robot html log file since only humans will read it. However now we want to add the information to a database at another company. If we want to get the information out to the database we would now be required to parse the logged strings. Which is possible but not practical.

Is there any way to add custom xml tag's in the RobotFramework created .xml file inside the robot test script. Such as

```
Set XML variable | serial_number | "1234"
Set XML variable | current_while_under_load | "0,4"
```

To get the following in the xml document

```
<DUT>
    <serial_number="1234">
    <current_while_under_load="0,4">
</DUT>
```

I understand that one can use rebot to post process/parse the xml however I would much more prefer to add tags inside the running scripts themselves.

Comment: Why not just write the needed variables in an external file, not the output.xml? Thus you'll have full control over its schema and content. The output.xml has a single purpose - to store all information about the run information, which you want to extend with something auxiliary.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use BuiltIn function "Set Suite Metadata"

```
Set Suite Metadata | serial_number | 1234
Set Suite Metadata | current_while_under_load | 0,4
```

The xml output file will then have the added lines:

```
<metadata>
    <item name="serial_number">1234</item>
    <item name="current_while_under_load">0,4</item>
</metadata>
```

Comment: If I wan this at the top suite only and regardless of which test cases or modules/suites ran, where do we do `Set Suite Metadata` ?

Comment: I am not all to familiar on how to set it up with suites, I assume placing it in Suite Setup wont work?

Comment: Would work if we were guaranteed that that Suite would be run. In my case, I have different folders (suites) and sometimes some suites are run and others not. For now I'll just store that info separately in an external file.